# Why is median motor nerve conduction velocity about 50 m/s?

Tags: neurophysiology, motor

I recently started reading *Fitzgerald's clinical neuroanatomy and neuroscience* ([Mtui, et al. 2015](https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=xb6iCgAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PP1&dq=info:4mKkwXXinnQJ:scholar.google.com/&ots=IlRUppz1XA&sig=zlK7r856NseByhMo4YYw6GGwYEY#v=onepage&q&f=false)) and reached chapter 12, *electrodiagnostic examination*, yesterday. The chapter deals, i.a., with nerve conduction studies and how to determine motor/sensory nerve conduction velocity (MNCV/SNCV). MNCV is about 50 m/s in a young, healthy adult as presented in the book. In a previous chapter, however, the reader is told that A$\alpha$ axons have conduction velocities ranging from 80 - 120 m/s which I also verified.

Isn't this contradictory? How can median nerve MNCV be less than the previously mentioned velocity? I know there are several fibers of a different type in the median nerve but shouldn't much rather scattering occur? What am I missing? Any help is greatly appreciated!

### References

Mtui, E., Gruener, G., & Dockery, P. (2015). *Fitzgerald's Clinical Neuroanatomy and Neuroscience*. Philadelphia, PA:Elsevier.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. We work differently to most SE sites, where we have a strict policy that all questions should [show evidence of prior research](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/993). Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google? This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful.